# Abnormal THD values for Audio Amp in any circumstances

Tags: operational-amplifier, multisim, total-harmonic-distortion

Using Charles Wenzel's "High Gain and Fidelity Audio Amplifier" (source:https://www.radiolocman.com/shem/schematics.html?di=335167) as my final project for my freshman year due this Saturday, I have tons of problems when trying to recreate the same audio amplifier circuit.
[image]

I've asked my professor and asked how my circuit can be improved. He said that I should have added ground to this circuit.

[image]

(Recreated by Multisim 14.1)

Before adding ground, The THD values would reach over 100%, even if I crank it up to the maximum designated input value, 21V.
My professor said that what I done is totally unnecessary, since high voltages could result in abnormal THD values.
He was right about cranking the voltage values, and adding ground to the circuit does lower the THD values. But this still didn't solve the problem of abnormal THD values.

[image]

(Input: Vrms=0.1mV, Frequency=1kHz)

So the input value isn't the main reason why I got high THD values. Other factors could contribute to THD values, but reading the source multiple times, I still couldn't find the answer to how to lower its THD values, and get the same results as Mr.Charles Wenzel did.

[image]

If you want more info about the Op-Amps I use, check "Texas Instruments" for more info, since I can't post any more links.

Appreciate all the constructive feedback, thanks. :)

Comment: _"input value, 21V"_ That would certainly clip the input stage. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm curious, do you know what the THD of a square wave is? Have you looked it up?  (Or better yet, calculated it -- have you done harmonics (Fourier series) yet?) What is the overall gain of this circuit, and what would the expected input and output voltages be?

Comment: @winny  I wanted to create the same result as the original one that Mr. Charles Wenzel did. In other words, to replicate and recreate the whole process like he did. He did not specify what input source it is. I assume its 18 volts from the last paragraph of the web source, and yes, it'll definately clip the circuit. I tried to find the values for the input source, but in vain.  It'll probably be better if you clicked on the source and read the passage.

Comment: @TimWilliams Since "Engineering Mathematics" is not available for the freshman year in my university curriculum, the answer for your first two questions is no.  As for the overall gain, expected output and input, etc. All these values aren't specified clearly in the passage, and what I can only do is purely guesswork, which is, to input values that I think fits for this circuit, since the other values listed have the same THD values.

Comment: @TimWilliams Our professor didn't really emphasis on the THD part, as from what I observe from other groups' presentation slides, they just give a THD value and simply explained what THD is.  Put it simply, anything beyond the basics that is not included in our session will be questioned by our professor.

Comment: With 9 V Vcc, this won't have anything useful come out.

Comment: You got two opamps at the input with gain 34 each, so that's a total gain of 1156. Gain is so high the amp is going to clip with any signal higher than a few mV on the input. Noise will also be enormous. So either use a few mV signal on the input, or reduce gain.

Comment: What opamps did you use?

Comment: @bobflux You can check the link in my post. It's right there.

Comment: OK LM358 should work. But the gain is way too high. BTW you should look at the signal on the oscilloscope first, only when that looks good, use the distortion analyzer. Because the shape of the signal gives a lot more information about what's wrong than the THD%.

Comment: @bobflux I've now added the Transient Graph to the post. Don't know if it means the circuit is OK to go or not.

Comment: @bobflux Also, for Multisim, it's kinda impossible to change the values of the op-amp component, so its only possible to change the values of Vcc or the input.

Answer (score 1):

When the article says 18 V it's talking about the supply voltage, Vcc, not the signal voltage.

Try increasing the supply voltage to 18 V and reducing the signal voltage to something like 1 to 100 mV (the position of the volume control R18 will have an effect on the input signal as well) and see what the distortion is with those voltages. If you find that the signal is clipping reduce the signal level.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, since I have exams yesterday and today. Thanks for your suggestion, I lower the signal voltage to 1mV, the THD values are around 0.327% . As for 100mV, result shows that THD vaule is around 42% .

Comment: However, if I changed both GNDs into ground, like the one that is connected to the voltage source, its THD values went straight up to 105% . Why is that?

Comment: Also, the article that I posted has a bunch of Vcc value. What makes you think that Vcc = 18V and not the other values? Just asking for clarification.

Comment: @omocron_vic You should have one ground and one Vcc. When the article says 'With a good speaker and 18 volts it's surprisingly loud' they mean that Vcc is 18V, they also mention Vcc=12V because they were trying it with different values. I'm not too familiar with Multisim but I see unconnected power pins on the op-amps, I know in LTspice each op-amp symbol gets it's own power connections even if it's part of a dual or quad package, I don't know that you can leave them unconnected in Multisim or not.

Comment: Did you mean all the op-amps that have a cross on one side of a the pin? This is considered normal. Take U2A and U2B as an example, since U2A pin 8 is already connected, U2B will not have anything connected at all. The same thing works for pin 4 as well. This is because its a dual op-amp, where pin 8 is equivalent to VS+, while pin 4 is equivalent to VS- .

Comment: I don't know if this is the right explanation to it, but this is the best I can come up with.

Comment: Okay, so Multisim must work differently than LTspice as far as that goes.

Comment: Also as Audioguru pointed out, your volume control is connected wrong and will change the DC bias. The control should go from the signal output to ground with the wiper going to the 1uF capacitor. The capacitor is to keep the ground connected pot from affecting the DC op-amp bias.

Comment: Could you specify which 1uF capacitor it is, and where the control should be put? I assume the control should be put after the 1000uF capacitor, and the wiper should be connected to the wire with C4 included.

Comment: @omocron_vic C6. The pot acts as a voltage divider for the input signal, the wiper is the output of the divider. Turn the pot so the wiper is at the end where the signal is connected you get full signal in, turn it to the end connected to ground you get no signal in. There will be a DC path to ground, C6 will keep that from affecting the bias voltage created by the two 330k resistors.

Comment: @omocron_vic  I've thrown together an LTspice simulation, having rouble getting it to work so far. Will report back if I figure it out, but it appears R13 and R14 set the transistor bias so this needs to be adjusted to reduce crossover distortion.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3Md04XS
I assume this is what you meant for the volume control.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the output signal should be shown on an oscilloscope so that you can reduce the input signal to about 2.6mV peak (output of 3V peak divided by the gain of 1156) and eliminating clipping at the output.

In the second schematic, the volume control is wired wrong then it affects the biasing of the first two opamps.

The first two opamps amplify the input offset of maybe 6mV to severe clipping. Reduce it by adding a coupling capacitor between these opamps.

Comment: Doesn't the component C4 in the first schematic imply that this is a coupling capacitor? Or do you mean that I should add another capacitor between U1A and U1B in the first schematic?

Comment: Yes, a coupling capacitor must be between U1A and U1B to prevent the input offset voltage of U1A to be amplified 1156 times causing the output of U1B to be slammed against a voltage rail causing severe distortion. Then U1B must have an input bias resistor.